# How to preview text excerpt from large file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JS (& SO), but I have a webpage where I upload a file sometimes as big as 500mb. The user takes a file from their OS and I want to preview the file in a `<pre> </pre>` box before sending off to a http endpoint, but for performance reasons I'd rather not read the entire file and then slice out the first few lines.

If possible, I'd like to just read the first few lines instead. This could be the first few bytes too if that's easier, there's no strict cut off point.

Currently I do this to read the file:

```
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("mailingFileText").innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    };
}
```

...and I set it inside this:

```
<pre class="pre-scrollable" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> 
    <p id="mailingFileText"></p>
</pre>
```

But this isn't overly feasible for really large files. Can anyone help?

Comment: stream it from a backend

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to test your site

Code a Example:

**jQuery**

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: './wiki-stevenjobs.txt',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'text/txt; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
            $('p#mailingFileText').html(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            $('p#mailingFileText').html(err);
        }
    });
});
```

OR

**Javascript Pure:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "./wiki-stevenjobs.txt", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/txt; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("mailingFileText").innerHTML = xhr.response;
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

500mb too much more 10minutes is depend a server, is best 10mb minimum.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, they add the file from the OS and I need to preview it before POSTing it to a http endpoint